# ag-grid angular wrong row order after initialization

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am experiencing weird behavior in ag-grid for angular and don't know if I am doing something wrong or that is a bug.

After initializing aggrid with

```
this.gridOptions = {
  enableSorting: true,
  rowHeight: 50,
  suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
  enableColResize: true,
  domLayout: 'autoHeight',
  rowSelection: 'single',
};
```

and

```
  <ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    [rowData]="articleArray"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    (cellClicked)="showDetails($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady()"
    (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()"
    (gridSizeChanged)="sizeToFit()"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```

And getting the resulted order of rows in the grid by

```
  updateArticleOrder() {
    const result: string[] = [];
    this.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(rowNode => result.push(rowNode.data.id));
    this.articleOrderChanged$.emit(result);
  }
```

I notice that the order is different from the original input used in `[rowData]="articleArray"`. To be precise, 11 items have been shifted to the bottom of the grid and the grid starts at original index 11. Why is that and how can I avoid it? After sorting and `updateArticleOrder()` being called inside `onModelUpdated()` I get the right order again, with index 0 displayed when I click the first row.

**[EDIT]** I notice that I get this problem only when initializing the grid. When my articleArray updates after the grid is already visible, `this.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort` gives me the new items in the correct order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a bug which comes from using [domLayout]="'autoHeight'". As a temporary solution try to set [rowBuffer] to some high number, eg [rowBuffer]="10000"

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much.

Comment: rowBuffer should be a number **not** a string